# The buttons in a repeat don't hide/show after refreshing the panel the repeat is in?

Tags: xpages

I have a repeat that has buttons embedded in it.  The repeat is in a panel.  When the user clicks a button the button should hide/show (I partial refresh the panel).  The repeat is tied to a Domino view and I see the other values that I from that view get updated in the repeat, so, it does not seem like a view index issue (I refresh the view index in my code.)

If I use context.reloadPage() in my button onclick code then the buttons will hide/show like they should, but, that seems like I am using a sledge hammer!  Any suggestions on how to get the buttons to recompute the visible property when the panel that holds the repeat is rendered?  Another strange thing is that the visible property gets computed three times whenever I refresh the panel that holds the repeat.

thanks, Howard

Comment: How do you calculate the hide/show options for the buttons? Can you add the code for the xp:button?

Comment: Are you using scope variables?

Comment: How do you compute the rendered property? Are you using the # (@ runtime ) or $ ( at page load ) ?

Answer (score 1):

I think your looking for

```
getComponent("<id>").setRendered(true / false);
```

Comment: Good try!  But, that hides all the buttons in the repeat!  I somehow need to get the id of each button in the repeat.   Or, is there a way to use "this" to get the parent button (I assume this in an event returns the event object and not the containing button?)

Comment: the reason it hides all the buttons is repeats don't treat each control in it uniquely. Any action applied to a control in a repeat row is applied to all. If you have access to the teamroom that comes with the ExtLib you should look at the custom control "mobileThread", this faces your issue where there is a reply / delete button and a expand / collapse image in each row, each row being a reply of a document. I used a custom js file to create a map  that i used to keep track of the controls and update elements by getting the index of the row. its a little complicated but works very well

Comment: Question ... why don't the buttons recompute the rendered property when the containing panel is refreshed (after the nutton is clicked)?  I can get the buttons to hide/show if I do the context.reloadPage...

Comment: is the rendered property your using '#{javascript: }'  or '${javascript: }', the first will run when ever there is a refresh, the latter will run only once during page load. sounds like your issue ?

Comment: Unfortunatey, it is #, that would have been easy!

Comment: there must be something else going on i've refreshed repeats before and its computed a render property for a panel inside it, have you tried putting a print out to see is it being run? perhaps the expression is not returning true at this time ??

Comment: Using a print statement in the rendered property does show the script is computing properly.  I can reload the page and then the buttons will display properly.  Let me try to simplify this to a simple XPage that I can post or email.  I have tried both a partial refresh of the panel that holds the repeat and a full refresh.  The only thing that works is the reloadPage()...

Answer (score 1):

Hi For Repeat control's entry is used to make our head hard. Because handling the entry by SSJS, we can get the value and set the value. But rendering part, id of the repeating component are same for all. So if we try to give reder as false. It hides all of our repeating component.

Try to use the following., [Put this in button onclick, and see the value of below]

```
var entryValue= getComponent("repeat1").getChildren().get(0).getValue()

getComponent("inputText1").setValue(entryValue)
```

But in client side we can easily handle. Because the id of the DOM object is unique for all repeating component.

```
var id1="view:_id1:repeat2:"+'2'+":button1"
document.getElementById(id1).style.display="none"
```

This will hide the third entry of your repeat control component.

[Please see the post, You may get better idea](http://kramkumarmca.blogspot.in/2012/04/dynamic-table-and-getting-row-values.html)

Comment: '#{javascript:IndexVar}' - you can also get index of our enrty.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.  My original solution was getting values from the repeat rows (using the collection object, which was a viewentrycollection and using getColumnValues) to compute the rendered property for the buttons.

Instead, I created a viewScope variable (a Vector) that holds the state of the buttons (which set of buttons to show).  This gets populated in the beforePageLoad event of the page.

The button onclick code updates this viewScope variable after performing its processing.  All works very nice now.  I guess it was something in the JSF lifecycle that kept the buttons from being properly updated.  Using the viewScope variable works fine.

Answer (score 0):

With addition to what Ramkumar said, you can use the index variable in the repeat control to identify each and every occurrences inside the repeat control. You will get more idea, if you inspect with element from firefox[You might need firebug].  Usually the field mentioned inside a repeat control itself can be considered as an array